# NVMe for 16.04 OS

Tags: 16.04, pcie, nvme

Would Ubuntu run on the "**250GB Samsung 960 Evo M.2 2280 NVMe PCIe 3.0**" card?

(I have a  *Dell Notebook PCIe* slot.)

Comment: Seems like you changed this into a completely different question? Or am I misunderstanding? If you have a different question, I think you should just ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

**Adding to Peter Ark's answer:**

A NAS Backup Box with 2+ drives would be great for backups, as you can use it to save backups for all of your devices, and it will then make more backups in each of the drives, so even if a drive fails, you would still have a backup in the other drives.

Comment: I have attached an external RAID-1 system. It works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on a lot of things. For what will you use it, capacity, price and transfer velocity are generally some of the most important criteria.

Buy a SSD with enough space for your day to day apps and for some documents that you work with. For most people 120 to 250 GB should be enough.

The best choice for backup is not to have your backup disk connected all time to your computer. Because if anything happens to your PC it can affect also the backup, like virus for example. Consider moving your backup HDD to an external box.